# Are the position indices (quartiles, median, mean) of distribution in classes always different from those of the unit distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, descriptive-statistics, median, interquartile

**Are the position indices (quartiles, median, mean) of distribution in classes always different from those of the unit distribution?** If so, for what reason?

In theory, since the class distribution is a summary, they should never be the same, but if there is a lot of data I'm not really sure about that.

Let's take an example:

*dati = 22 29 30 20 33 19 22 33 33 15 26 31 30 34 34 33 17 22 17 34 15 17 15 17 23 27 32 26 16 26 28*

and those breaks: 15  19  24  29  34

**values  unit distribution/distribution in classes**

1st quartile = 18/18.44444

3rd quartile = 31.5/30.47727

mean  = 25.03226/24.70968

median = 26/25.25

...   = a/b

What I'm asking for is: is that possible that a=b?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "distribution in classes"? Are you just asking about any distribution on the unit interval, compared to the uniform distribution?

Comment: @StephanKolassa If I refer to R, by "distribution in classes" I refer to the values grouped into classes (intervals) whose extremes can be obtained with hist(...)\$breaks. To give an example, the calculation of the mean for unit distributions is mean(data) while for distributions in classes it is sum (h$mids * h\$counts) / sum (h\$counts) where h = hist (...)

Comment: Please edit to add more details. You seem to be referring to histogram, but it is hard to understand what exactly do you mean.

Comment: @Tim is better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Are the position indices (quartiles, median, mean) of distribution in classes always different from those of the unit distribution?** If so, for what reason?
>
> In theory, since the class distribution is a summary, they should never be the same [...]

We are talking about comparing sample estimates to estimates obtaining aggregated data from a histogram.

- As you noticed, in the second case the data is aggregated, so it is less precise and obviously differs from the raw data, so the results could be expected to differ.
- Can they be the same? Sure, it can happen by chance. Same as you could by chance get the same value as the sample mean by drawing a completely random value from a random number generator.
- How likely is the above? If we are talking about continuous random variables, the [probability is equal to zero](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142730/px-x-0-when-x-is-continuous-variable).
- There are algorithms to make the estimates from histograms more precise, [for example for median](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548275/how-to-calculate-median-via-interpolation).